# What did I do wrong here when working with an API?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, swiftui

First: I'm a beginner with Swift and SwiftUI. I would appreciate any help, even if its not related to my question!
Now my question:
To practice SwiftUI and API's I want to build a little app that displays some data about the coronavirus, very simple. This is the API I used: [Coronavirus API](https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all).
Now this is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GlobalResult: Decodable {
    var cases: Int
    var deaths: Int
    var recovered: Int
}

struct Statistics : View {
    @State var global: GlobalResult!

    var body: some View {
         VStack {
              VStack {
                Text("\(self.global.cases)")
              }
         }.onAppear() {
               ApiShared.shared.getData()
         }
     }
}



class Api {
    @Published var data: GlobalResult!

func getData() {
    let url = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all"

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in

        if err != nil {

            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }

        let json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(GlobalResult.self, from: data!)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.data = json
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
}

class ApiShared {
    static let shared = Api()
}

struct Statistics_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Statistics()
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work! I followed some tutorials on YT and could make it working. Could anyone please help me?
When I remove the
if Statement
it says "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the `localizedDescription` that gets displayed inside the if statement?

Comment: tbh, i dont really know that, its from a tutorial. but i assume thats the error

Comment: a couple things: avoid using `!` to force wrapping an optional value. instead of print((err?.localizedDescription)!) do print((err?.localizedDescription) ?? ""). that should help you debug further and whats going on.

Comment: same with `data!`. i didnt realize you had a bang in two different places. whereever the fata error is happening, you want it to fail gracefully so you can continue debugging your issue

Comment: What should i do with the "!"?

Comment: no. that's not the error. the error you are getting is because you are forcing unwrapping on a nil object when decoding: `try! JSONDecoder().decode(GlobalResult.self, from: data!)`. and it's crashing because you are receiving an empty data object and an error an you are forcing unwrapping on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with SwiftUI, but it seems to me that the problem is in it. Something with your var data. 
I changed your function a bit.

```
func getData() {
    let url = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all"
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, responce, err) in
        if let error = err {

            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let responce = responce{
            print(responce)
        }

        if let data = data{
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(GlobalResult.self, from: data)
                print(json)
            } catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
```

The result was obtained. Try changing the function in the same way and you will see printed response in console and it will mean that problem in var data indeed.

Comment: Yeah, you right! I see it in the console. Now I have to figure out how to display it.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer gives a good way to safely get the data without crashing, but you're still not setting the result of the getData() function to your global variable in your view. Try changing your getData() function to return a GlobalResult object like this:

```
func getData() -> GlobalResult? {
     let url = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all"
     let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
     session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, responce, err) in
         if let error = err {
             print(error.localizedDescription)
             return nil
         }
         if let responce = responce{
             print(responce)
         }

         if let data = data{
             do {
                 let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(GlobalResult.self, from: data)
                 print(json)
                 return json
             } catch{
                 print(error.localizedDescription)
                return nil
             }
         }
     }
     .resume()
 }
```

This returns a GlobalResult value if it was successful, and nil if not. Then in your Statistics view you can do this:

```
struct Statistics : View {
@State var global: GlobalResult!

var body: some View {
     VStack {
          VStack {
            Text("\(self.global.cases)")
          }
     }.onAppear() {
           let result = ApiShared.shared.getData()
           if result != nil {
               global = result
           }
     }
     }
 }
```

This gets the result of the getData() call and sets it to the global variable if not nil. I don't think you need the @Published var in the Api class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i type "return nil" or "return json" it says "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Comment: make sure your getData() function definition is written so that it returns a GlobalResult? type. See the top of my first code snippet.